# Bootstrap: Multiselect: Onchange deselect the checkbox

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-multiselect

I have implemented bootstrap multiselect dropdown with checkbox.

I want to allow users to select only 3 options or checkboxes. If user try to select more than 3 then I would like to show alert message and not to allow them to select 4th option.

Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
  $('#template').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
    numberDisplayed: 1,
    maxHeight: 250,
    includeSelectAllOption: false,
    onChange: function(option, checked, select) {
      if (checked == true) {
        var last_valid_selection = null;
        if ($('#template option:selected').length > 3) {
          alert('sorry');
          var $element = $(this);
          $($element).prop('checked', false);
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

How can I do that onchange event of multiselect dropdown?

Comment: Can you share the jsFiddler?

Comment: Could you please attach your html code?

Comment: Here is a jsFiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/Lefdrx8z/

But it is not showing checkboxes here.. I don't know why...

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski.. Here is the HTML code:

`<select name="template" id="template" style="font-family:arial;font-size:13px;height:30px;" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="1">Abyss Premium</option>
   <option value="2">Accolade Premium</option>
   <option value="3">Allure</option>
   <option value="4">Allure Corporate</option>
   <option value="5">Ambiance Premium</option>
   <option value="6">Antique Premium</option>   
  </select>`

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem almost entirely through jQuery. The basic idea is that your onChange handler will want to look at the current count of selected options in the select. If there are more than x selected options, then add a disabled attribute to the other options using

`$("#typeCheckboxSelect option:not(:selected)").prop('disabled', true);`

Otherwise, if there are less than the x selected options, then you want to make sure there are no disabled options, by selecting all the options and disabling them, using

`$("#typeCheckboxSelect option:disabled").prop('disabled', false);`

Do note that after any changes to the base select html, you will want to refresh the multiselect.

Below, I put together a working example of the above description. Let me know if you have any questions on the code.

```js
var maxCount = 3;
$("#typeCheckboxSelect").multiselect({
  includeSelectAllOption: true,
  enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
  numberDisplayed: 1,
  maxHeight: 250,
  includeSelectAllOption: false,
  onChange: function(option) {
    //Get selected count
    var selectedCount = $("#typeCheckboxSelect").find("option:selected").length;
    //If the selected count is equal to the max allowed count (3 here), then disable any unchecked boxes
    if (selectedCount >= maxCount) {
      $("#typeCheckboxSelect option:not(:selected)").prop('disabled', true);
      $("#typeCheckboxSelect").multiselect('refresh');
      alert("Only allowed to select " + maxCount + " options.");
    }
    //If the selected count is less than the max allowed count (3 here), then set all boxes to enabled
    else {
      $("#typeCheckboxSelect option:disabled").prop('disabled', false);
      $("#typeCheckboxSelect").multiselect('refresh');
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<select id="typeCheckboxSelect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value='test1'>Test One</option>
  <option value='test2'>Test Two</option>
  <option value='test3'>Test Three</option>
  <option value='test4'>Test Four</option>
  <option value='test5'>Test Five</option>
  <option value='test6'>Test Six</option>
</select>
```